# Getting Problem In RecycleView with TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am a new Programmer, actually I was trying to make an app. I was trying to make an activity that uses RecyclerView to Show TextInputEditText with spinner and TextView. It means that I was trying to make an activity that uses Recyclerview and In the layout of Recycler View, I have used Text Input Edit Text and Spinner and TextView. I have put these three in a single layout. But the main problem that I facing is that when I launch my app with my code then it remains blank activity it is not showing TextInputEditText nor spinner and nor TextView.

So the conclusion is I want to show [TextInputEditText, Spinner and TextView] in RecyclerView But my code is returning Blank Activity.

Here is my code:-

It is my adapter class:-

```
public class SpecialHoursAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecialHoursAdapter.SpecialHourHolder> {


//    private ArrayList[] mDataSet;

    private List<SpecialHorusModal> modal = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    public SpecialHoursAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpecialHourHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_hours_layout_card, parent, false);
        return new SpecialHourHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpecialHourHolder holder, int position) {


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modal.size();
    }

    public static class SpecialHourHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextInputEditText editText;
        private Spinner spinner;
        private TextView textView;

        public SpecialHourHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.special_hours_editor);
            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_special_hours_date);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker_special_horus);


        }
    }


}
```

It is My MainActivity:-

```
public class SpecialHoursActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView containerRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager first, container;
    private SpecialHoursAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_special_horus);




        //     mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.activity_special_horus_main_recyclerview);
        containerRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.layout_container_recyclerview_special_hours);

        //    mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        containerRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        first = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        container = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


//        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(first);
        containerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(container);
        containerRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Here is my RecyclerView Layout:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/special_hours_editor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Special Hours"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="20" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_special_hours_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_picker_special_horus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="00:00" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My Main Layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_special_horus_main_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/layout_container_recyclerview_special_hours"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have not used any modal class because I don't know how to use it with Widgets.

Comment: Your RecyclerView data (modal field) seems empty. Are you adding items to it? Obviously no list items will be shown if the data is empty.

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni Sorry I am not using any modal and In this case, I don't know how to use modal can you please help me by updating the code

Comment: I am taking about the variable named `modal` in your Adapter class

Comment: If you have a fixed numbers of items in you recycler view, you don't need the modal variable at all. Just return the number from the `getItemCount()` method

Comment: To begin with, you seem to have poor understanding of how `RecyclerViewAdapter`  works. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni I want to add plus button which was not used now but in future I want to add because the items are not fixed so after clicking plus button, the items change their number but  I don't know how to use modal in these case now

Comment: So in that case, call modal.add() when the user clicks the button

Comment: You need to store the data in your items in the `onBindViewHolder()` method

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni Ok But can you help me to fix the main  problem now?

Comment: Your main problem being there are no items in your adapter, which you need to add as I described above

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni Can you please update the code and add as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the data to your adapter

```
public SpecialHoursAdapter(Context context,List<SpecialHorusModal> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.model=data; //it will show your recyclerview  
   
}
```

**we could not show the Recyclerview with empty data**

Comment: If I use your code then how will to add this data in Main Activity?

Comment: SpecialHorusModal data=new SpecialHorusModal();
List<SpecialHorusModal> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(data); 

pass this list

Comment: They are right. Don't expect people to write your code instead learn how those components work and if you find a problem after you do, you can ask it here on SO. The answers here totally solve what you asked for but saying "This does not solve my problem" without understanding it right just shows the lack of research. -1 good luck. 

Comment: @Quanta Thanks for advice and I have edited your answer little bit now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the data your Adapter holds, adapter with empty data will obviously show no items.

```java
public class SpecialHoursAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SpecialHoursAdapter.SpecialHourHolder> {


    private List<SpecialHorusModal> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    public SpecialHoursAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //Call this in onClick of your button, passing it the object to add
    public void addItem(SpecialHoursModal item) {
        items.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChange(); //This is important
    }
    
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpecialHourHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_hours_layout_card, parent, false);
        return new SpecialHourHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpecialHourHolder holder, int position) {
        //Bind the data to view for the object at this position
        SpecialHorusModal item = items.get(position);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class SpecialHourHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextInputEditText editText;
        private Spinner spinner;
        private TextView textView;

        public SpecialHourHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.special_hours_editor);
            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_special_hours_date);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_picker_special_horus);


        }
    }


}
```

When your button is clicked, or you need to add an item:
`adapter.addItem(new SpecialHorusModal(...));`

Comment: @Quanata This Does Not Solve My Problem